# Redboot password recovery

Tags: passwords, arm, recovery

I have an ARM device with redboot programmed into the chip (freescale powerpc).
I want to flash a custom image on the device but redboot is password protected.
There is no documentation on the internet on how to recover redboot's password, even on redboot's official documentation.

Anyone have an idea about this ? 
PS: the board is not a developer board so no debugger. but i do have serial access.

Thanks !

Comment: ARM device using a powerpc core?

Comment: Yes an mpc85xx board